# Is there profiles in Apache Aries Blueprint like Spring Profiles?

Tags: java, spring, apache-karaf, aries, spring-profiles

I would like to know if there is anything similar to Spring Profiles for Apache Aries Blueprint. I am trying to conditionally load stuff when deploying Blueprint files to an Apache Karaf container, but I have still not figured it out how to do it.

Splitting the Blueprint XML file into two pieces is not an acceptable solution to me, but maybe there is any other solution that I don't know that can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something like profile within one bundle bounds it is signal that something wrong is happening. In pure modular environment you should not need things like that, because service model keeps you customizations hidden. In traditional JEE applications where your WAR is one big assembly you may not have different options.

You have two options here. First - which you don't like to apply - is to drop additional blueprint file in deploy folder or have additional bundle. Second is to use "blueprint-ext" namespace which allows you to load resource from disk location.